# Alinhar texto ao centro da imagem - Bootstrap

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap, front-end, bootstrap-4

Estou usando **Bootstrap 4** pro desenvolvimento do site. Pensei em começar incluindo a estrutura básica do grid juntamente da imagem e de um h1 (para testar o posicionamento).
Envolvi a imagem e o h1 em uma div que dei a classe de `img-ds`. Essa classe contém um `position: relative` e um `display: inline-block`. No h1, coloquei uma classe que chamei de `texto-ds` que contém um `position: absolute`. Após isso, pensei que se eu usasse os parâmetros `top: 50%` e `left: 50%`, meu texto ficaria totalmente centralizado ao centro, mas obtive este resultado, com o h1 pendendo um pouco pro lado inferior direito (o X é aproximadamente aonde eu esperava que o h1 ficasse posicionado):

[image: Resultado apresentado]

Código **HTML** deste trecho:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 p-0">
      <div class="img-ds">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/bg-ds.jpg">
        <h1 class="texto-ds">Teste</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Código **CSS** deste trecho:

```
.img-ds {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.texto-ds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

Fiz um *codepen* para facilitar a visualização de vocês. Reparem que, em primeira  mão, o h1 fica alinhado ao centro corretamente da imagem. Porém, quando a resolução é de um dispositivo móvel, o h1 pende pro lado direito.

[Codepen Demonstrativo](https://codepen.io/ChoiYun/pen/gOpjjZY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atualize o seu código na classe `.text-lg-center` para:

```
.text-lg-center {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     color: black;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Texto no centro]

Comment: Wow! Muito obrigado, você é o melhor. Mas, uma pergunta: qual a função da propriedade transform? Como ela está agindo nesse contexto? E por que os valores estão negativos? Se eu alterar os valores de top e left, terei que alterar os valores do transform também?

Comment: A propriedade `transform` dependendo do valor passado pode ser usada no elemento para rotacionar, inclinar, aumentar / diminuir a escala e etc acesse esse link (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform) para obter mais detalhes. Quando é colocado `top: 50%` e `left: 50%` o `<h1>` é centralizado no elemento pai, note que você empurra o elemento para a direita e para baixo em `50%`, por conta disso parece que o elemento não foi centralizado, então é usado `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` no qual o elemento vai transladar para a esquerda e para cima centralizando o elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Altere a classe para 
.text-lg-center {
  color: white;
}

E a linha do H1 no HTML para 
Teste

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi. Devo alterar qual classe para .text-lg-center?

Comment: Nao sei porque nao aparece o texto completo do que escrevi...seria isto "Alterar o nome da classe .texto-ds para .text-lg-center. E a linha do H1 no HTML para <h1 class="text-lg-center">Teste</h1>"

Comment: Bom, eu alterei o nome da classe `.texto-ds` para `.text-lg-center` e substitui a linha do h1 para `class="text-lg-center"`. Acontece que literalmente nada mudou, o texto continua pendendo pro lado direito, mesmo com os parâmetros top e left em 50%. Por que ele não fica exatamente no meio?

Answer (score 0):

adicione `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` no texto-ds

Comment: Por algum motivo, ele quebra e cai pra fora da imagem bem abaixo dela. [print](https://prnt.sc/rjqhff)